# whitespace in select dropdown, pulled from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, select, whitespace

I'm using this to populate a dropdown:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user from `users` order by user asc") or die(mysql_error());
            echo '<select name="user" class="user">';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<option value=".$row['user'].">".$row['user']."</option>";
            }
            echo '</select>';
```

But the source is this:

```
<select name="user" class="user"><option value=joe bloggs>joe bloggs</option>
```

So when i do this:

```
var user = $('.user').val();
```

It only sees "joe" not "joe bloggs"?? Any ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user from `users` order by user asc") or die(mysql_error());
        echo '<select name="user" class="user">';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($row['user']).'">'.htmlspecialchars($row['user']).'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
```

Corrected for you :)

Comment: out of interest why is it that i can accept answer for certain amounts of time?? v frustrating!

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the value in quotes:

```
echo "<option value=\"".$row['user']."\">".$row['user']."</option>";
```

Also, make sure to `htmlspecialchars()` in order to escape possible quotes *in* the name. E.g.,

```
$user = htmlspecialchars($row['user']);
printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $user, $user);
```

Answer (score 2):

inside the while loop try:

```
echo "<option value=\"".$row['user']."\">".$row['user']."</option>";
```

basically adding a quote to the value inside the option

Comment: beat me to it :p oh and I vote for the htmlspecialchars() function too, will save you from many headaches :D

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes `"` around attribute values..

your html should look like

```
<option value="joe bloggs">joe bloggs</option>
```